Locked out of my PC that is encrypted with VeraCrypt
I have hard drive lock installed on one of my PCs with VeraCrypt.
I’m completely locked out. PC boots straight to screen asking for VeraCrypt password
I cannot get into the BIOS since the PC is hard drive encrypted.
I have tried the following:

Restarting.
Hitting escape key both at startup and when password prompt displays.
Searching for passcode.

I cannot uninstall the battery on the PC easily as it is an all in one with no removable battery.
I don’t like having a bricked computer. I posted in the VeraCrypt forums but they're dead.

This does not seem right.  The "BIOS" boots before the hard drive is read, so encrypting the drive should not prevent you from getting into the BIOS.  What make/model laptop do you have?    As general advice, not all "BIOS's" use the escape key.    Try spamming the F1, F2, Del, F10, F11 and F12, TAB key - ie one key per attempt, multiple times until you get in to BIOS - normally one of the above will work.   That said, what are you going to do once you get into it?   Do you have a USB with an OS that you can blow away your existing install and reinstall on?

What is your end goal here?
If you didn't create a backup mechanism to get into your encrypted drive it is unlikely you will ever be able to recover any data on this system.

If you have a 'hard drive lock' installed then isn't it expected that it ask for a PW?

VeraCrypt should not prevent access to UEFI just prevent access to the operating system. Your post on the VeraCrypt forum isn’t that old. If you can’t decrypt the drive due to not knowing the password or the correct password not successfully decrypting the drive. Replacing the drive is the only solution. Uninstalling the battery will NOT give you access to the drive or the firmware settings if VeraCrypt is by chance prompting for the password prior to accessing the firmware step (which will doubt). Just mentioning removing the battery should not be seen as a solution to any problem you face

All-In-One computers still have batteries for BIOS.  It might be a pain to get to, but its there.  Also, look up the manual for that computer, there may be a jumper to clear the BIOS.

You asked the same questions less than 12 hours before this post. You might try waiting for answers on the original question before asking it again.

I’m voting to close this question because OP posted the same question just a few hours before.
